# Output of array of arrays in Powershell / Powercli gets truncated w/ellipses

Tags: arrays, powershell, powercli

The purpose of my script is to get the entire list of VMs from our vcenter, check to see if they have DNS entries - if the dns entry is null then output the VM name and corresponding IP address.  Pretty simple, but I'm getting tripped up combining the VM name array with the IP address array.  Here's what I mean:

```powershell
$mainArray = @()
$vmArray = @()
$ipArray = @()

$vms = Get-VM | select Name, @{N="DnsName"; E={$_.ExtensionData.Guest.Hostname}}, @{N="IPAddress"; E={$_.Guest.IPAddress[0]}}

foreach ($vm in $vms)
{
   $dnsname = $vm.DnsName
   $ipaddr = $vm.IPAddress
   $vmname = $vm.Name

    if (!$vm.DNSName) #if DNS name is null
    {
       $vmArray += $vmname
       $ipArray += $ipaddr
     }
}       

$item = New-Object PSObject
$item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'VM Name' -Value $vmArray
$item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'IP Address' -Value $ipArray

$mainArray += $item

$mainArray | ft -wrap -autosize
```

This outputs the two columns next to each other, but the output is separated by commas and is truncated with an ellipse.  I know that there's a better way to do this, so I'm open to suggestions.  Also be curious to know how to make this work just for my own understanding.  Appreciate the help everyone.

Comment: Are you just concerned with the output on screen? I'm guessing the data is there. You are just seeing what PowerShell does displaying arrays to console. The data is still there. Would this only generate only one row? Did you expect more results in your table?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  Yes, the data seems fine and yes it only generates one row.  There's a lot of data (over 300 VMs) and it's getting chopped off at the 5th VM.  I'd like this to output as a list displayed in two clean columns (one value per row).  One column for VM name, the other for corresponding IP address.  I think I'm close but not sure if I'm going about this in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are populating an array outside your loop. I don't have access to PowerCLI right in front of me now but we should be able to remove most of that code as it appears to be redundant and needless. Continuing after `$vms` being declared

```powershell
$vms | Where-Object{!$_.DNSName} | ForEach-Object{

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'VM Name' = $_.Name
        'IP Address' = $_.IPAddress
    }
} | ft -wrap -autosize
```

Before you made a two arrays. One for names and the other ips. Then you took those 2 arrays and made a single object with those two properties. I removed the need for the if statement with the `Where-Object{!$_.DNSName}`. Now all the objects being processed are the ones you want.

You could really do this is in one/two lines using the same logic.

```powershell
Get-VM | Select @{N='VM Name';E={$_.Name}}, @{N="DnsName"; E={$_.ExtensionData.Guest.Hostname}}, @{N="IP Address"; E={$_.Guest.IPAddress[0]}} |
    Where-Object{!$_.DNSName} | Select "VM Name","IP Address" | Format-Table -wrap -autosize
```

Again, I cannot test but it should work. If there are any errors they should be easily correctable. Assuming I figured out your issue in the first place.

## About the ellipses

PowerShell has a variable `$FormatEnumerationLimit` that governs how many array elements are display in console output. There is a good article that discusses it on [TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/20/change-a-powershell-preference-variable-to-reveal-hidden-data.aspx)

By default `$FormatEnumerationLimit` is set to 4

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt.  I see how this works, and it gets it done a lot more efficiently.  This is a much better solution.  However, just for my own understanding, can you explain how I could have manually displayed the two arrays ($vmarray and $iparray) in two separate clean columns?

Comment: @user1932885 Not sure I understand since my answer was trying to show you just that. One column is easy as you just type just `$vmarray` and `$iparray`. PowerShell works best with object so creating one as you were attempting to do is the way to go. Else you could manipulate string output but that is not required and messy.

Comment: That last part about manipulating string output is what I am curious about.   Using the original script, I can display output in separate columns but the output is comma separated and truncated.  Is there no way to handle this?  I know you gave me a better solution, but I'm just trying to understand why my original script can't achieve the same result.

Comment: @user1932885 I update the answer to cover what you are looking for i think

Answer (score 0):

Matt, I had found that link earlier but didn't find it very helpful since it makes the output garbled and doesn't breakout the values by row.  This is how I was able to make the original script work:

```
$i=0

write-output $vmArray |
foreach {
new-object psobject -property @{
                                VMName = $_
                                IPAddress = $ipArray[$i++]
                             }
    }   | ft -auto -wrap
```

Rather unconventional, but does work nonetheless.  There really should be an easier way to combine array side by side, but I digress.  Thanks a ton Matt.

Update:  This is probably more conventional:

```
    For($i=0;$i -lt $vmArray.Count;$i++)
    {
    $item = New-Object PSObject
    $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'VM Name' -Value    $vmArray[$i]
    $item | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name 'IP Address' -Value $ipArray[$i]
    $mainArray += $item
      }

$mainArray | ft -wrap -autosize
```